# What verbs should be used after "there is" and "there are"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, questions

Somebody told me these are incorrect in grammar usage:

1. There are few people join
   our party.
2. There are a few cookies to
   share you.

Please anyone tell me which parts are incorrect and what kind of the verbs could be used after "There is & There are"

Comment: @KateBunting - Or *share with you* if the speaker is also eating the cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean immediately after "there is" or "there are," no verb can grammatically be used in that position.